# Call multiple data sets in Listplot

Tags: list-manipulation

I am generating numerical data sets with a for loop and the table command. These data sets are named `data[i]`, where $i$ is the counting variable of the `For` loop.

I'd like to call all this data sets, i.e. `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]` etc. in the `ListPlot` function to plot them all at once. I know that this can be done by writing explicitly `ListPlot[{data[0], data[1], ...}]`. However, this is inconvenient regarding a huge number of data sets, let's say 100. Is there a way to use a loop inside this command itself? Or is there another way to call all the data sets at once, where you can define the starting point and ending of the counting variable $i$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `Evaluate@Table[data[i], {i, 0, numberOfLists}]` within `ListPlot`, or look up [Array](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html); `Evaluate@Array[data, numberOfLists, 0]` should work as well.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. Works perfectly well.

Answer (score 2):

You say you are using `Table` when generating the data sets; why not store all the data sets in a list, using `Table`, to begin with? Like e.g.

```
datasets = Table[data[i], {i, 0, 100}]
```

Then plotting them would be as easy as `ListPlot[datasets]` as you say. Maybe this can be a good opportunity for you to restructure your code =)

If you need to keep working with `DownValues` of `data[i]`-stuff, then you can do

```
ListPlot[Evaluate[data /@ Range[0,100]]]
```

But why start on `data[0]` and not `data[1]`? All *Mathematica* iterators start on 1 by default.

Comment: Alright, thought that would kill my sublists (because I wanted to plot each of my data sets individually), but it doesn't. 

I just set the iterator to one in my loop, but yeah I should stick to the default case. There is no reason to start with data[0].